# How to install Vue Hooper slider properly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I've been learning Vue.js 2 for a few weeks for my app and I don't want to use Bootstrap carousel because of no built in swipe functionality.

So I'm trying to use Vue.js slider like Flickity and Hooper. But for some reason, the CSS is not importing and so I cant see any style on the slider. These are the steps I've done to test the slider

```
vue create slider-test
```

then

```
npm install hooper
```

and then I try to follow this
https://vuejsexamples.com/a-customizable-carousel-slider-optimized-for-vue/

Comment: Hey Daniel, could you please add more context? For example, could you show us the source code where you try to put the hooper component? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import the CSS:

```js
import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css';
```

Also, there are two typos in the linked installation procedure:

- `import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';         // from not form`
- The closing `</template>` tag is missing a slash.

Here's a working version of their example component:

```html
<template>
  <hooper>
    <slide>
      slide 1
    </slide>
    <slide>
      slide 2
    </slide>
  </hooper>
</template>

<script>
  import { Hooper, Slide } from 'hooper';
  import 'hooper/dist/hooper.css';

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    components: {
      Hooper,
      Slide
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Bro your a life saver! I thought I just have to follow the instructions on the documentation. I've seen a lot of slider docs and not a single one of them that says to import the css.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Even Hooper doesn't import it on their main page example (they should), though they do on their [getting started](https://baianat.github.io/hooper/getting-started.html#use-hooper) page  (but only in 1 of 4 examples)